# Creating a CMap which holds another CMap as a value

Tags: c++, collections, mfc

I am trying to create a CMap which has a CString as a key and a CMap as a value. Obviously  the following is not working but I have no clue how it is working.

```
CMap<CString, LPCSTR, CMap<CString, LPCSTR, int, int>, CMap<CString, LPCSTR, int, int>> xyWhatEver;
```

Anybody has an idea how to implement such a datastructure in c++ using CMap?

Comment: Which library does `CMap` come from? (I’m suspecting MFC but I have no idea). Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: I would suggest using data structures (probably unordered_map) out of STL. In your case, either tr1::unordered_map or something from boost.

Answer (score 2):

CMap doesn't have copy constructor. I'd suggest using STL classes instead of mfc. Of course you can replace CMap to CMap*, but this will require additional allocating/freeing steps.

```
typedef CMap<CString, LPCSTR, int, int> tInnerMap;
CMap<CString, LPCSTR, tInnerMap*, tInnerMap*> map;
```