# MFC CMap. Store a cmap inside a cmap

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to have a CMap:

```
CMap<long,long, Cmap<long,long,long,long>>
```

So my data structure will have long as a key and it will redirect to a value, and the value will be a cmap of longs inside of it.

Example: if i receive "1" so it will send me to a CMap.
and if i receive 2 it will send me a different cmap.

is this possible ?

Cant use std/stl map. must use MFC CMap object in this project.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use std::map? You could have `std::map<long, std::map<long, long> >`.

Comment: I have to second the use of `std::map`. I have no idea why Microsoft insists on always reinventing the wheel... badly.

Comment: cant use stl/std on this project. only MFC Cmap. according to this url http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/8e5a426c-b545-4d13-971c-4c2a13fb2bcc/ they say its not possible to put Cmap inside cmap ?

Comment: @DaveRager MFC predates the official release of the STL by a few years, and its design was influenced greatly by the limitations the compiler(s) it had to be compatible with. Sure, with 20/20 hindsight some design choices in MFC were bad and cause problems. But once the CMap code was used by devs, Microsoft couldn't just up and change it and say "oh, well use this other thing now!" And let's not kid ourselves: the STL isn't without its warts either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9604620/416627), a `CMap` does not have a copy constructor which is why you cannot contain one within the other. You should still be able to store a *pointer* to a `CMap` however.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I don't think there are any restrictions on what you store in the CMap so you could do this, but</s>
I would highly recommend you use the standard library containers. They are standard for a reason. That makes them more maintainable and makes the code easier to read by future developers. MS is also going to be doing out of band C++ compiler updates with the new compiler so you may get bonus improvements by just recompiling in the future.

```
std::map<long, std::map<long, long> > myMapOfMaps;
```

**Edit:**
I checked the header for CMap and @DaveRager is correct, there is no copy constructor so your only option would be to have a CMap of long to CMap* OR to use the std::map. I would highly recommend the standard map.

**Edit2:**
Based on your statement that you are not allowed to use the standard library in your project then you will have to resort to having a map of `long` to `CMap*`. I would suggest your talk to the architect and find out why they do not want you to use standard library collections. Once you understand the design of the standard collections, they make the code much more clean and readable.

Comment: if i std:: there is not map option. I believe the architect disabled it so we could only use CMap. all along the project we use CMap

Comment: @ilansch - Did you `#include <map>`. I don't know how you could "disable" the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for verifying. It's been a few years since I did anything with MFC.

Comment: @DaveRager - Thanks for making me look (you got +1 for that ;) ). I have to deal with MFC everyday and have been converting to standard library containers whenever I have the chance since the code is much cleaner (IMHO) that way. The CMap/CArray stuff is horrid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

the solution to store a pointer to CMap works but too risky.

Another solution that could be in mind, which we use, is to make a map of objects that contains a CMap. the class will contain identifier and a cmap inside of it.
meaning:

CMap  LiveDisconnectionCache;

Thanks again

Comment: I don't think the second idea will work. If you are holding a `CMap` and not a `CMap*` then you have the same issue as the original issue. `CMap` does not have a copy constructor. What version of VS are you using? Are you restricted from the entire standard library or just the collections. If you are in VS2010 or 2012 then you could have a `CMap` of long to `unique_ptr<CMap>` or `shared_ptr<CMap>`. Then you don't have to worry about leaking the `CMap` pointers.

Comment: Hi, the 2nd idea did not work. What i did was to create additional object that holds a CMap. and in the primary cmap i build it like this: CMap<long,long, Object, const Object&> and create copy constructor to the Object. I am checking so will load final answer when finish. tnx